# Proportion Estimates - Shrink to the Mean Based on Sample Size

Tags: mixed-model, data-mining, regularization

**Set-up:**

One of the fundamental elements of direct marketing is choosing which lists of prospects to select and send an offer to. There are hundreds of lists on the market to choose from and each list will contain a specific number of records you can send an offer to.

I have a table of historical performance of list. For each, the number of times a promotion was sent to someone on that list, along with the number of responders is given. So, the table might look like this - it is a made up example with only a couple of lists versus the hundred actually but the very small response rates (p) are realistic.

```
lists<-data.frame(listName=c('A','B','C','D','E'),numberPromoted=c(1000,5000,25000,35000,1654),numberRespond=c(3,45,98,350,5))
lists$p<-lists$numberRespond/lists$numberPromoted
```

I am looking to use linear programming to optimally allocate list selection in future campaigns. So, given the current number of records available in each list at the preesent time and the best estimate of the response rate of the list (p), choose how many records from a list to select, given constraints.

**Problem:**

My question is how to best go about estimating p. Given these small response rates, I would like to shrink those without "adequate" information to a mean value. The naive way is to say that there has to be at least X number of records promoted before we trust the p estimated empirically. I am wondering if there is any other method that makes sense?

For example, does it make sense to treat the list as a random effect and shrink the estimate? I **THINK** this code is shrinking the estimates of the response rate (p) to the mean rate for smaller cells.

```
install.packages("lme4")
library(lme4)
install.packages("arm")
library(arm)

#make individual 1/0 records
Lists<-data.frame(
listName<-c(replicate(1000,"List A"),replicate(5000,"List B"),replicate(25000,"List C"),replicate(35000,"List D"),replicate(1654,"List E")),
outcome<-c(replicate(997,0),replicate(3,1),replicate(4955,0),replicate(45,1),replicate(24902,0),replicate(98,1),replicate(34650,0),replicate(350,1),
    replicate(1649,0),replicate(5,1))
)


    #random intercept model
    mod<-lmer(outcome~1 + (1|listName),data=Lists,family=binomial)

    invlogit(coef(mod)$listName[1,1])
    invlogit(coef(mod)$listName[2,1])
    invlogit(coef(mod)$listName[3,1])
    invlogit(coef(mod)$listName[4,1])
    invlogit(coef(mod)$listName[5,1])

List    Modeled P   "TRUE" P
A   0.004241    0.003000
B   0.008602    0.009000
C   0.003981    0.003920
D   0.009924    0.010000
E   0.003961    0.003023





  #compare raw versus shrunk modeled estimates

raw<-sqldf("select listName, avg(outcome) as raw_p from Lists group by listName")
    meanRaw<-sqldf("select avg(outcome) as total_p from Lists")
    modeled<-c(
    invlogit(coef(mod)$listName[1,1]),
    invlogit(coef(mod)$listName[2,1]),
    invlogit(coef(mod)$listName[3,1]),
    invlogit(coef(mod)$listName[4,1]),
    invlogit(coef(mod)$listName[5,1]))

    plot(x=as.numeric(raw$listName),y=raw$raw_p, col="blue")
    points(x=raw$listName,y=modeled, col="red")
    abline(h=meanRaw)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks about right as a strategy.  There is presumably a population of lists of which these are a sample.  If so, they're a natural random effect candidate.  And you are currently shrinking to the mean.

You might even know something about the lists on, e.g. their source or the demographic they target or some such.  Then you could shrink towards group means for groups or features actually relevant to your problem, rather than just the grand mean.  If so, put that information on the right hand side of the bar instead of the list indicator.

Also, since the counts are very small you also might want to look at using a Poisson GLM instead of the binomial.  For that, predict the `numberRespond` with `family=poisson` and use `numberPromoted` as `offset`.  Then recover the proportions with a simple division.  In any case, I would recommend avoiding any applications of linear regression here.

On a computational note: you don't have to make individual records.  Binomial GLMs in base R's `glm` and in `lme4` will take the aggregated output and give you the same results.

Finally, it is possible that your subsequent optimisation routines can be made to make use of your uncertainty about the estimated proportions.  If there is much you will probably do better by pushing it through to the later analysis.  In your current formulation `ranef` or a posterior sample will give you this information.

Comment: Something like: `mod <- glmer(outcome ~ 1 + (1 | listName) + offset(lengthsOfLists) + data=Lists, family=poisson)`  Don't forget the offset!

Comment: Thanks for the comments! For a couple clarifications: 1) In order to use a poisson, I would write mod<-lmer(numberResponded~1 + (1|listName),data=Lists,family=poisson, offset=numberPromoted)? I have not understood using poisson versus binomial for 0/1 data.

Comment: 2) To incorporate information about the type of list (not just the name), would I add those variables, for example listType which may be the demographic profile of the list by doing the following, assuming the existing individual level data construct and listType as a column in the data frame:   mod<-lmer(outcome~ listType+ (1|listName),data=Lists,family=binomial)?

Comment: That would work, though I was thinking of `outcome ~ 1 + (1 | listType)`.  (this replaces names of lists with numerical or factorial descriptions of lists).  But there are a lot of other possibilities.  I would read up a bit about `lme4`'s use of formulae to see the implications of different choices.

Comment: I think on your code in the first comment: mod <- glmer(outcome ~ 1 + (1 | listName) + offset(lengthsOfLists) + data=Lists, family=poisson) you would mean for "glmer(outcome..." to be "glmer(numberResponded.." instead, since outcome is a 1 or zero and  numberResponded would be a count of responses.

Comment: Yes, quite right.  I meant the count.

Comment: if you happen to receive email notifications, I was revisiting this and wondered if your suggestion of using outcome ~ 1 + (1 | listType) in the comment above presumed that there were multiple examples (records) in the data table that shared the same value of listType? Is that what would cause shrinking to a group mean and not the grand mean? I am not sure why this would be the case (shrink to group mean versus the grand mean and what would make this setup different than listType as the random effect)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to "manually" shrink the response rate to the sample mean using a quadratic penalty for deviating from the mean. If one uses quadratic loss function (with weighting each list by numberPromoted to take into account the amount of data in each list) then this becomes a modified version of weighted ridge regression with shrinking to the mean as opposed to shrinking to zero (aka "poor man's bayesian")

The penalty coefficient can be tuned using cross-validation.

Comment: @Yevgeny- Just to confirm, is the random effect as I have in my question indeed shrinking to the mean? Can you sketch the approach you are suggesting?

Comment: I think so, e.g. see page 9 for the same model: http://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st572-larget/Spring2007/handouts13-4.pdf

Comment: As for the sketch, it is just weighted linear regression with quadratic penalty (where penalty is model parameter value minus sample mean squared summed across all five parameters). Each list corresponds to one data point, and the weights are equal to numberPromoted. Solving it requires inverting a matrix 5x5. This is not a univariate regression (I was wrong) so one needs a bit of matrix algebra here (so no simple closed-form solution for the penalty coefficient unfortunately)