# Categorical logit Predictor with too many different levels

Tags: classification, categorical-data, logit, many-categories

One of the predictors I had in a logit model is "City". Problem  is this categorical variable has too many factor levels. e.g. In a Sample of $\sim 3000$ there are already $\sim 200$ different cities.

Is it fair to still retain City as a predictor or should I purge it entirely from the model? An alternative is to retain, say, the top five most common cities and then code all the rest as a new factor level "Others". The top city occurs $\sim 60$ times but by the fifth common city this occurance drops down to 30. Some cities occur only once or twice in the dataset.

PS. One problem I face (if I retain all factor levels) is that certain levels occur in the validation set but not in the training set. Then the model complains at validation time.

PPS. On more reading, I found sugesstions to use combine.levels() from the Hmisc package in `R`. Maybe that will work, though not sure how exactly yet.

Is there an elegant way to deal with these issues?

Comment: Have you considered replacing the ordinal `City` variable with characteristics of those cities? In particular, ones that are theoretically related to your model? For example, you might replace `City` with population density, if that's related to the outcome you're trying to predict. This would require finding the relevant data and joining to your current data; but, if your validation set has a new city, it won't throw an error so long as you can find the relevant characteristics.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25324/proportion-estimates-shrink-to-the-mean-based-on-sample-size  and this http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2012/07/modeling-trick-impact-coding-of-categorical-variables-with-many-levels/

Comment: The applicability of this depends on how of course you are using the predictor. If this is your main variable for inference, it probably doesnt work and I would collapse into an other group as you said. If the main goal is for prediction or if this is a control variable, it can work.